# check checbox before submitting a form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a signup form with username, email and password along with agree with terms and policies checkbox.

The problem is that, I have validated all other input types in the follwing ways but it doesnt seem to work with checkbox.

I just want to alert user that they need to agree to the policy before submitting the form but it's looking like a huge stone please help me guys. Thanks!

```
<form ng-submit="form(signup.$valid)" name="signup">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkPolicy" required> Agree the <a href="#">terms and policy</a><p ng-show="signupForm.checkPolicy.$error.required && !signupForm.checkPolicy.$pristine" class="help-block">You must agree to our terms and policies.</p>
<button type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need ng-model for checkbox for validation to kickin

Answer (score 0):

It's my opinion that it's more intuitive for both you and the user that your "Signup" button remains disabled until the required checkbox is checked.

Angular makes this very easy with `ng-disabled`:

```
<form ng-submit="form(signup.$valid)" name="signup">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkPolicy" ng-model="checkAgree"> Agree the <a href="#">terms and policy</a><p ng-show="signupForm.checkPolicy.$error.required && !signupForm.checkPolicy.$pristine" class="help-block">You must agree to our terms and policies.</p>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!checkAgree">Signup</button>
</form>
```

Bonus fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ntwrc7c/

If you want to go the `validate` route with the `required` attribute, simply add a `ng-model` to your checkbox input.

```
<form ng-submit="form(signup.$valid)" name="signup">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkPolicy" ng-model="checkAgree" required>
    Agree the <a href="#">terms and policy</a>
    <p ng-show="signupForm.checkPolicy.$error.required && !signupForm.checkPolicy.$pristine" class="help-block">You must agree to our terms and policies.</p><br>
    <button type="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ntwrc7c/1/